# String Concatenation Issue with the If Else Logic in Python

Tags: python

I have this table:

| name | address | city | Result | Required Result |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Sara | abc | NY | Sara, abc, NY | Sara, abc, NY |
|  | def | CN | , def, CN | def, CN |
| Andrew | hij |  | Andrew, hij, | Andrew, hij |
| Mike |  | MD | Mike, , MD | Mike, MD |

I am getting the Result as in the "Result" filed as above table using the below Python code:

```py
    def calculateFullAddress(name, address, city):
        if (name == " "):
            return  address  + ", " +  city
        elif (address == " "):
            return  name  + ", " +  city
        elif (city == " "):
            return  name  + ", " +  address
        else:
            return  name  + ", " +  address  + ", " +  city
```

I need to get the results as in the "Required Result" field. Which logic should I use? Thanks

Comment: In each return?

Comment: replace the whole code under that function with this line

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```py
return ', '.join([i.strip() for i in [name, address, city] if i.strip()])
```

instead of all that if else statements

This pretty much does the same, just using some in-built functions and methods in Python

```py
def calculateFullAddress(name, address, city):
    return ', '.join([i.strip() for i in [name, address, city] if i.strip()])

print(calculateFullAddress('Name', 'Address', 'City')) # with everything
print(calculateFullAddress(' ', 'Address', 'City')) # with no name
print(calculateFullAddress('Name', '', 'City')) # with no address
print(calculateFullAddress('Name', 'Address', ' ')) # with no city
```

Output

```
Name, Address, City
Address, City
Name, City
Name, Address
```

Tell me if its not working for you...

Comment: Did you actually try this?

Comment: This does not even work if name or city is empty, not to talk 'bout the address.

Comment: @interjay yes, i've added its results too

Comment: I just tried it and it seems it is working. Please give me some time so, I can test it in multiple scenarios. Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

Try the following method:

```py
def calculateFullAddress(name, address, city):
    res = ""
    for value in [name, address, city]:
        if value != "":
            res += value + ", "
    return res.strip(", ")
```

Comment: it gives `Name,  , City` if there's no address

Comment: Yes, because you are using `" "` which is not an empty string. If a single space is needed, change the string compared with value in line 4.

Answer (score 0):

Yours didn't work because, it maynot be a string with a single space (`" "`) in it, in case if its empty. The following code will work :-

```py
def calculateFullAddress(name, address, city):
    if not name.isalpha():
        return f"{address}, {city}"
    elif not address.isalpha():
        return f"{name}, {city}"
    elif not city.isalpha():
        return f"{name}, {address}"
    else:
        return f"{name}, {address}, {city}"
```